# Create a Sequence With Two of Each Element Satisfying Certain Distance Criteria

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sequence, permutation

Given a sequence of distinct items Sa, we wish to create a sequence Sb (composed of the same items in Sa, but in a different order) such that the sequence S = Sa + Sb (sequence Sb appended immediately after sequence Sa) satisfies the following properties:

- The distance (number of positions) between the two occurrences of item I in S is at least some number T for all items I.
- If items I and J are within N positions in Sa, then I and J are not within N positions in Sb.

I've been able to program the first stipulation in Python fairly simply.  However, the second one is where I struggle.  Essentially, I'm just wanting these two things:

- I want the second sequence to have its items "far away enough" from their occurrence in the first sequence.
- I don't want neighbors of the first sequence to also be neighbors in the second sequence (with N referring to the distance in which items are considered neighbors).

Here's what I have so far:

```
import random

clips = list(range(10)) # arbitrary items
choice_pool = clips[:]
Sa = clips[:]
random.shuffle(Sa)
Sb = []
count = len(Sa)

threshold = 0.5*len(clips) # the minimum distance the item has to be away from itself in the concatenated sequence
while len(Sb) != len(Sa):
    jj = random.randint(0, len(choice_pool) - 1)
    # we want clip a1 to be at least threshold away from clip b1
    if count - Sa.index(choice_pool[jj]) >= threshold:
        Sb.append(choice_pool[jj])
        del choice_pool[jj]
        count += 1

print("Sa:", Sa)
print("Sb:", Sb)
print("S :", Sa + Sb)
```

Do you have any advice on how to also achieve the second stipulation, while always guaranteeing such a sequence exists (not ending up in an infinite loop)?  Thanks.

Comment: Does _any_ `Sb` go, or you need a way to randomly pick one of _all_ such arrangements?

Comment: @user58697, I need a way to randomly pick one of all such arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

I would take out the chance of randomness out of the equation.  With randomness you are never guaranteed that you aren't stuck in an infinite loop.  There are better improvements to this algorithm but here is the base.

```
import itertools as it

def filter_criteria(sequence):
    #put your filters here return True if you find a sequence that works
    pass 

for sb_try in it.permutations(sa, len(sa)):
   if filter_criteria(sa+sb_try):
       return sb_try

return "no permutation matches"
```